# Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to populate a Dataset based on a specific Selection ID  but get the error

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Not exactly sure why I have this error.

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\HarryPothead.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        OleDbDataAdapter dba = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Person] WHERE [StatusIdFrn] = '" + statusID + "'", conn);
        dba.Fill(ds, "PersonName");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["PersonName"];

        drpPerson.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        drpPerson.DataTextField = "PersonName";
        drpPerson.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
```

Advice perhaps on how to overcome this.

The databsase I am Selecting from is an Access database and the table I am selecting from three fields, PersonId which is of the type AutoNumber, PersonName which is of the type Text and StatusIdFrn which is of the datatype Number.(drpPerson is a DropDownList control)

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Person] WHERE [StatusIdFrn] = '" + statusID + "'"
```

To this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Person] WHERE [StatusIdFrn] = " + statusID + ""
```

As [StatusIdFrn] is numeric, you need to discard the single quotes as they indicate a text type.